# How do I apply functions to matrices?

Tags: r, function, matrix

Are there any packages/functions in R that allow users to apply functions to matrices?

For example the Taylor expansion of the matrix M when the exponential function is applied is exp(M)=1+M+M^2+M^3+...

Now let:

```
M<-matrix(1:4,nrow=2)
```

But if I were to input the command `exp(M)` in R, it would just give me the matrix: `matrix(c(exp(1),exp(2),exp(3),exp(4)),nrow=2)`

This is not what I want. Does anyone know if it is possible to apply matrix functions in R?

Comment: e.g. `library("sos"); findFn("{matrix exponential}")`.  There's an `expm` function in the `Matrix` package and I believe also a dedicated `expm` package.  One or the other of those also have a matrix logarithm. I don't think there's a safe or useful way of  generically applying nonlinear functions to matrices; what specifically are you looking for?  (The matrix "square root" is not uniquely defined, although the Cholesky decomposition is probably the most common version ...)

Comment: Thanks. I have a feeling that I didn't need to find the function of the matrix after all. My problem is that I have to find the solution to a fixed point equation involving matrices that is very complicated. If it is that difficult to get the function of a matrix, then it probably is not the correct method to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer goes to @Ben Bolkner.
You can use `expm` function of `Matrix` package.

Please see the code below:

```
library(Matrix)
M < -matrix(1:4,nrow=2)
expm(M)
```

Output:

```
2 x 2 Matrix of class "dgeMatrix"
         [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 51.96896 112.1048
[2,] 74.73656 164.0738
```